# Flex project eat 30% CPU

Tags: apache-flex

I have created a  complex flex project. It consumes around 30% CPU, then I cut down the browser?

What it can be the reason?

Comment: Any ActionScript based tool does that for me. Air and Flash kill an entire CPU core on Linux, it seems.

Comment: Nobody's asked the burning question: What is your app doing?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that i've recently been burnt by is statefull assets pulled in from a swc.  I recently took the time to change all the statefull skins to stateless skins and my cpu droped from about 40% to about 3-4%

Check out [this post](http://patrickhansen.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/05/flex-stateful-skins-vs-stateless)

There could also be many other problems with the efficiency with you code but if you do use steful skins then it's bound to be that.

Answer (score 0):

Flex can be greedy, but 30% is a bit high.  Please tell us the computer specifications, software (browser, OS) and what the Flex is doing.  E.g.: Videos can eat up lots of CPU

Comment: Hello - thanks for the answer

I have Windows XP SP2. CPU CELERON 2.66. 1.25 Gb memory. Browser - repeat in both IE and FF - event if the borower is cut down. Also I'm not play any video in application.

Comment: And how old is your computer?  (Celeron covers a ten year period of time.)  Celeron is also a relatively weak CPU.  The 30% maybe normal for such a CPU.  Again, what is your Flex app doing?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just the render loop can consume a lot of CPU time.

If you've raised your framerate in the application, this could be a source of such a high idle usage.

Alternatively, you can try lowering the framerate of your app, it may help.  Depending on your app, 12 or 15fps might be enough.

But in general, consuming huge amounts of CPU like that is likely your app trying to do something.